# Function returns an uncaught reference error

Tags: javascript, node.js, datatables

I'm trying to create a countdown timer in my Datatable using the below code. However, I'm getting an Uncaught reference error - "timers is not defined". I can't figure out why.

```js
var table = $("#myTable").DataTable({
  processing: true,
  serverSide: true,
  ajax: {
    url: "/getOrder",
    dataSrc: "orderStr",
  },
  columns: [
    { data: "id" },
    { data: "market" },
    { data: "order_type" },
    { data: "trade_amount" },
    { data: "strike_price" },
    { data: "filled_status" },
    { data: "kof_frame" },
    { data: "time_frame" },
    { data: "expiration_date" },
    { data: "timestamp" },
    {
      data: "timestamp",
      render: function (timestamp) {
        for (var i = 0; i < timestamp.length; i++) {
          //console.log(tableRows[i]);
          var entryDate = timestamp;
          const second = 1000,
            minute = second * 60,
            hour = minute * 60,
            day = hour * 24;

          countDown = new Date(entryDate).getTime();

          setInterval(function () {
            let now = new Date().getTime();
            distance = countDown - now;

            days = Math.floor(distance / day);
            hours = Math.floor((distance % day) / hour);
            minutes = Math.floor((distance % hour) / minute);
            seconds = Math.floor((distance % minute) / second);

            timers =
              days + "d:" + hours + "h:" + minutes + "m:" + seconds + "s";
          }, 1000);
        }
        return timers;
      },
    },
  ],
});
```

Comment: You never *declared* something called `timers`, so when you try to `return timers` you get an error. Only one second later (at least) would the interval run and write to the implicit global `timers` but *right now*, that doesn't exist.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comment. Can you please let me know how I can fix it. Much apreciated

Comment: You just need to properly declare your timers variable. use `let timers` to initiate it outside of your setInterval's scope, then you can reassign its value later with a `timers = ...`

Comment: It looks like this will need much more than a simple fix.  The `render` is looking for a value, so whatever that function returns will be what you render.  But then what is `setInterval` doing?  It updates a value, but does nothing to update the UI.  At the end of the function you pass to `setInterval` you'll need to update the UI somehow.  Either via some API exposed by DataTables or manually by targeting the specific HTML element and updating it.

Comment: Fix it to do *what* exactly? Right now the code fails because the instructions are nonsensical. I do not know what is expected to happen - what a "working state" would be, so I don't know how to reach it. Right now your code is trying to immediately return a value that will only be calculated one second later. Which cannot work, because of lack of time travel. Moreover, the value will be re-calculated every second. But a return only runs once. What *should* be happening here?

Comment: @Slim ...and then the `return` always produces `undefined`, and the `timers` is never used. So that fix doesn't really fix much. Just produces some dead code.

Comment: A DataTables column `render()` function is used to calculate the initial values of the column in question (and it iterates the table rows for you, so you don't need that `for` loop, if you added it for that reason... it's not clear...). The `render()` function returns a single value per column cell, as part of the DataTable's initialization. It won't change after that, unless you change the source data and refresh the table, or use the DataTables API to change the data (and re-draw the table). Bottom line: putting a `setInterval()` in a `render()` function is the wrong approach, conceptually.

Comment: But it's not entirely clear (to me) what "success" would look like, so it's hard to suggest an alternative approach. I expect it would be to draw the table once, and then use the approaches hinted at by David in their comment.